# Non greedy regex within parenthesis and contains text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Suppose I have a string that looks like

```
test = 'this is a (meh) sentence that uses (random bits of meh2) and (this is silly)'
```

I want to extract ONLY text inside the parentheses if it includes the word "meh".

Doing a regular non-greedy regex to match anything within parentheses:

```
re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', test)
```

Returns

```
['meh', 'random bits of meh2', 'this is silly']
```

Trying to do that to only include the first and second contents:

```
re.findall(r'\((.*meh.*?)\)', test)
```

Returns

```
['meh) sentence that uses (random bits of meh2']
```

I want a regex to return only

```
['meh', 'random bits of meh2']
```

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Make the first `.*` non-greedy.

Comment: ^yup:  `\((.*?meh.*?)\)`

Comment: Ah, missed that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of allowing all characters, you can allow all characters except the closed parenthesis by using `[^\)]` where the `.` is now.

```
re.findall(r'\(([^\)]*meh[^\)]*?)\)', test)
```

Comment: Interestingly, comparing the two options on regex101.com, this version used 131 steps at ~4ms while the non-greedy version used 146 steps at ~1ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'\((.*?meh.*?)\)', test)
```

Comment: `r'\((.*?meh.*?)\)'` won't work. It should be `re.findall(r'\(([^()]*meh[^()]*)\)', test)`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Can you describe why the OP's code did not work and what the difference here is that might work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Why will non-greedy not work?  I've always preferred the `[^()]` approach because it feels more..explicit, but I can't think of any concrete examples that would break non-greedy.

Comment: @zzxyz With `this is a (meh) sentence that uses (random bits of meh2) and (this is silly)`, it is just a coincidence `\((.*?meh.*?)\)` works. You [can see it breaks with `(this) is a (meeeeeh) sentence that uses (random bits of meh2) and (this is silly)` already](https://regex101.com/r/0CoSVK/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - ah yes...lazy, but the regex starts asap.  thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the clarification and example! I have marked your solution as accepted

Comment: It is Worthwelle's answer, not mine :-)